# Are this inlining results common?

Tags: c, optimization, inline, inlining

Due to university work, I have to investigate a simple optimization, the inlining.

Here is the basic code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ITER 1000
#define N 3000000

int i, j;
float x[N], y[N], z[N];

void add(float x, float y, float *z){
    *z = x + y;
}

void initialVersion(){
    struct timeval inicio, final;
    double time;

    gettimeofday(&inicio, 0);
    for(j = 0; j < ITER; j++){
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
            add(x[i], y[i], &z[i]);
        }
    }

    gettimeofday(&final, 0);

    time = (final.tv_sec - inicio.tv_sec + (final.tv_usec - inicio.tv_usec)/1.e6);

    printf("Time: %f\n", time);

}
```

And here is the code with inlining:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ITER 1000
#define N 3000000

int i, j;
float x[N], y[N], z[N];

void inliningVersion(){
    struct timeval inicio, final;
    double time;

    gettimeofday(&inicio, 0);
    for(j = 0; j < ITER; j++){
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
            z[i] = x[i] + y[i];
        }
    }

    gettimeofday(&final, 0);

    time = (final.tv_sec - inicio.tv_sec + (final.tv_usec - inicio.tv_usec)/1.e6);

    printf("Time: %f\n", time);

}
```

Compiling using the option -O0 with gcc, the results are 14.27 seconds for the basic version and 4.45 seconds for the version with the inlining. Is that common? I executed the programm 10 times and the results are always similar. What do you think?

Then, compiling with the option -O1 the results are similar for both versions, 1.5 seconds approximately so I **suppose** that gcc does the inlining for me with O1.

By the way, I know that gettimeofday counts the overall time and not only the time used by the programm itself, but I am required to use that function specifically.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of question is "what do you think?"? SO is not a discussion forum.

Comment: The more you ask the CPU to do, the more it takes time, and a function call is expensive considering there is only a simple calculation to perform each time. Compilers optimizers remove more or less obvious unnecessary code, or might even rearrange the code.

Comment: I can edit the question and ask "Is it common?". I asked "What do you think" in order to avoid repetition because in the title I asked for the first one. @melpomene

Comment: Common for the compiler to do it for you? (Yes) or common to hand-inline like you did? (Not so much, though it can be useful in hotspots some times, but you have to measure to make sure you didn't just repeat a compiler optimisation and make things less readable for no benefit).

Comment: Common the results (14 seconds the normal version and 4 seconds the inlining version, saving 10 seconds) @JonHanna

Comment: Yes, it's common for inlining to save time, that's why the compiler does it for you after all. At the same time, it's not common for inlining to save much time when you compile with optimisations precisely because the compiler does it for you anyway. As I said above, it **can** sometimes be worth hand-inlining (and even more so with some other languages than C) but because it reduces readability for a gain the compiler would likely have done for you anyway in real use you would only do it in a hot path and measure to be sure you actually gained (you could even make things slower in some case).

Comment: Bottom line is why would you want the additional overhead of a function call and separate function stack frame to be created and released every time you add two `float` number together? Most (if not all) compilers are smart enough to optimize trivial functions calls by inlinining them.

Comment: I want to do it like that because I am required to. It is university work @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: That's fine. I remember lab exercises (of course that was back when the only computers available VAX, Univac, Amdahl or IBM...)

Comment: No need to *suppose*, automatic inlining is a standard optimization in any C compiler.  As long as you enable the optimizer, as you found out.  So doing it by hand is not necessary.  And can be harmful, you might inline *too much* and make processor caches less effective.  Maybe not today, but code very rarely ever gets smaller.  But most importantly, it is never good enough to compromise code readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's us analyze the assembly output generated by GCC 7.2 (with `O0`) for both versions of the code.

---

### Without inlining

First, let's check how much work has to be done by the computer to achieve the task with a separate function:

```
void add(float x, float y, float *z){
    *z = x + y;
}

int main ()
{
    float x[100], y[100], z[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
             add(x[i], y[i], &z[i]);
        }
}
```

For the above code, GCC produces an assembly as given below:

```
add(float, float, float*):
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movss   %xmm0, -4(%rbp)
        movss   %xmm1, -8(%rbp)
        movq    %rdi, -16(%rbp)
        movss   -4(%rbp), %xmm0
        addss   -8(%rbp), %xmm0
        movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
        movss   %xmm0, (%rax)
        nop
        popq    %rbp
        ret
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $1224, %rsp
        movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
.L4:
        cmpl    $99, -4(%rbp)
        jg      .L3
        leaq    -1216(%rbp), %rax
        movl    -4(%rbp), %edx
        movslq  %edx, %rdx
        salq    $2, %rdx
        addq    %rax, %rdx
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        cltq
        movss   -816(%rbp,%rax,4), %xmm0
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        cltq
        movl    -416(%rbp,%rax,4), %eax
        movq    %rdx, %rdi
        movaps  %xmm0, %xmm1
        movl    %eax, -1220(%rbp)
        movss   -1220(%rbp), %xmm0
        call    add(float, float, float*)
        addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
        jmp     .L4
.L3:
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
```

The processing part of the code takes approximately 32 instructions (instructions between `L4` and `L3` and that of `add` function).

A large majority of the instructions are used for making the function call.

A simplified way to understand how function calls work is:

1. arguments are pushed on the call stack
2. return address is pushed on to the call stack
3. the function is called
4. make a copy of the frame pointer
5. make room for locals on the stack
6. actual function code is executed
7. restorel the state as it was before the function call
8. return to the caller

The above steps (except 6th) take additional instructions to do the required processing. This is called the function call overhead.

---

### With inlining

Now let's check how much work the computer has to do if the function was inlined.

```
int main ()
{
    float x[100], y[100], z[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            z[i] = x[i] + y[i];
        }
}
```

For the above code, GCC produces an assembly output as given below:

```
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $1096, %rsp
        movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
.L3:
        cmpl    $99, -4(%rbp)
        jg      .L2
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        cltq
        movss   -416(%rbp,%rax,4), %xmm1
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        cltq
        movss   -816(%rbp,%rax,4), %xmm0
        addss   %xmm1, %xmm0
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        cltq
        movss   %xmm0, -1216(%rbp,%rax,4)
        addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
```

The processing code (instructions between label `L3` and `L2`) has around 14 instructions. In this assembly output, all the instructions which are responsible for making the function call aren't present which saves considerable amount of CPU cycles.

In general, the overhead of a function call is not relevant when your function's running time is more than several times of the overhead of a function call. In your code, the running time of your function is quite small and hence the function call overhead gains significance.

If you use the `O1` flag, the compiler indeed does the inlining for you. You can find out by checking the assembly generated with the `O1` or you can directly check the GCC manual for the [list of optimizations](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) which are tried with `O1`.

You can generate assembly output using the `-S` flag or you can do it online with [GodBolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) (the assembly outputs were taken from here for this post).